# Error while running Deep Convolutional Autoencoder

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to create a Deep convolutional autoencoder that the decoder architecture be the same as generator of DCGAN. But I am getting the error while running the model.
you can find whole of my code here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uO6eMBp4DmgEOaXY4iAuG9FpkYAasfG7?usp=sharing

part of my code here:

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()

    self.encoder = nn.Sequential( # like the Composition layer you built
        nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 3, 2, 1, bias=False),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(16, 16 * 2, 3, 2, 1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16 * 2),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(16 * 2, 16 * 4, 3, 2, 1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16 * 4),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(16 * 4, 16 * 8, 3, 2, 1, bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16 * 8),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(16 * 8, 16 * 16, 3),
        nn.Sigmoid()

    )
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(     16 * 16, 16 * 8, 3),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64 * 8),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(16 * 8, 16 * 4, 3, 2, 1, output_padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16 * 4),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(16 * 4, 16 * 2, 3, 2, 1, output_padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16 * 2),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(16 * 2,     16, 3, 2, 1, output_padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        nn.ReLU(True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(    16,      1, 3, 2, 1, output_padding=1),
        nn.Tanh()
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.encoder(x)
    x = self.decoder(x)
    return x
```

The full error I am getting is:

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d32e488e5d56> in <module>
      1 model = Autoencoder()
      2 max_epochs = 20
----> 3 outputs = train(model, num_epochs=max_epochs)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight, bias)
    452                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    453         return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
--> 454                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    455 
    456     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (2 x 2). Kernel size: (3 x 3). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how to correct it!

Comment: If you understand the error message, the general direction should be clear. How exactly you want to change the architecture is up to you: there are many, equally random ways to fix it.

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It tries to use kernel_size=3 (3x3). You have to lower the kernel size to 1 (1x1) or 2 (2x2), or modify your model somewhere before this layer.